Intercept significant, but confidence intervals around its standardized β include 0
I ran a HC (‘robust’) regression. The intercept is significant, which is reflected in the confidence intervals around the unstandardized betas. However, the CIs around the standardized β are quite wide and include 0; please see the table below.

Is that fine, or should I be concerned and am I doing something wrong? The dataset is available at here; all the steps of the coding are included below. (The table is patched together as I haven’t yet figured out how to generate the complete one seamlessly.)
Many thanks!
> load(file = "Amman.rda")
> library(sandwich)
> model <- lm(progress ~ opi + competence + integration + indegree + voterank, data = Amman)
> summary(model)

Call:
lm(formula = progress ~ opi + competence + integration + indegree + 
    voterank, data = Amman)

Residuals:
      Min        1Q    Median        3Q       Max 
-0.150864 -0.028803  0.003795  0.026640  0.124062 

Coefficients:
             Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)  0.496290   0.078140   6.351 2.69e-06 ***
opi         -0.424556   0.153329  -2.769   0.0115 *  
competence   0.010045   0.004462   2.252   0.0352 *  
integration -0.238163   0.099404  -2.396   0.0260 *  
indegree     0.023413   0.013545   1.729   0.0986 .  
voterank    -0.002266   0.003058  -0.741   0.4669    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 0.06614 on 21 degrees of freedom
  (10 observations deleted due to missingness)
Multiple R-squared:  0.5663,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.4631 
F-statistic: 5.485 on 5 and 21 DF,  p-value: 0.002205

> library(lmtest)
> coeffHC4 <- coeftest(model, vcov = vcovHC(model, type = "HC4"))
> coeffHC4

t test of coefficients:

              Estimate Std. Error t value  Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)  0.4962902  0.0808139  6.1411 4.299e-06 ***
opi         -0.4245559  0.1508714 -2.8140  0.010397 *  
competence   0.0100454  0.0044635  2.2506  0.035257 *  
integration -0.2381628  0.0805296 -2.9575  0.007517 ** 
indegree     0.0234134  0.0098380  2.3799  0.026873 *  
voterank    -0.0022659  0.0023894 -0.9483  0.353756    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

> conf_ints <- confint (coeffHC4, level = 0.95) |> 
     as.data.frame () |> 
     tibble::rownames_to_column("Variables") |>
     `colnames<-`(c("Variables", "95%CI_low", "95%CI_hi"))
> conf_ints

    Variables     95%CI_low     95%CI_hi
1 (Intercept)  0.3282284541  0.664351977
2         opi -0.7383101090 -0.110801602
3  competence  0.0007629805  0.019327796
4 integration -0.4056331442 -0.070692390
5    indegree  0.0029541503  0.043872647
6    voterank -0.0072348011  0.002703083

> library(dplyr)
> VIF_tol = vif(model) |>
     as.data.frame () |>
     tibble::rownames_to_column("Variables") |>
     mutate (Tolerance = 1/`vif(model)`) |>
     `colnames<-`(c("Variables", "VIF", "Tolerance"))
> VIF_tol
           Variables      VIF Tolerance
1         scale(opi) 1.493807 0.6694305
2  scale(competence) 1.175722 0.8505409
3 scale(integration) 1.392198 0.7182888
4    scale(indegree) 1.050531 0.9518994
5    scale(voterank) 1.414064 0.7071815

> model_summary <- summary(model)
> output <- model_summary$coefficients |> 
     as.data.frame () |>
     tibble::rownames_to_column("Variables") |>
     left_join (conf_ints, by = "Variables") |> 
     left_join (VIF_tol, by = "Variables") |> 
     mutate (across(c(2:4, 6:9), .fns = function(x) {format(round(x, 5), nsmall = 5)})) |> 
     relocate (`95%CI_low`, .after = Estimate) |>
     relocate (`95%CI_hi`, .after = `95%CI_low`)
> output[ ,7] <- format.pval(output[ ,7], eps = .001, digits = 4)
> output

    Variables Estimate 95%CI_low 95%CI_hi Std. Error  t value Pr(>|t|)     VIF Tolerance
1 (Intercept)  0.49629   0.32823  0.66435    0.07814  6.35133  < 0.001      NA        NA
2         opi -0.42456  -0.73831 -0.11080    0.15333 -2.76892  0.01150 1.49381   0.66943
3  competence  0.01005   0.00076  0.01933    0.00446  2.25151  0.03519 1.17572   0.85054
4 integration -0.23816  -0.40563 -0.07069    0.09940 -2.39592  0.02597 1.39220   0.71829
5    indegree  0.02341   0.00295  0.04387    0.01354  1.72862  0.09855 1.05053   0.95190
6    voterank -0.00227  -0.00723  0.00270    0.00306 -0.74103  0.46688 1.41406   0.70718

> library(lsr)
> etaSquared(model)
                eta.sq eta.sq.part
opi         0.15832698  0.26744774
competence  0.10468472  0.19445477
integration 0.11854396  0.21467219
indegree    0.06170723  0.12456734
voterank    0.01133971  0.02548222

> table <- nice_table(output)
> flextable::save_as_docx(table, path = "table.docx")

#For standardized betas:

> model_std <- lm(scale(progress) ~ scale(opi) + scale(competence) + scale(integration) + scale(indegree) + scale(voterank), data = Amman)
> coeffHC4_std <- coeftest(model_std, vcov = vcovHC(model_std, type = "HC4"))
> conf_ints <- confint (coeffHC4_std, level = 0.95) |> 
     as.data.frame () |> 
     tibble::rownames_to_column("Variables") |>
     `colnames<-`(c("Variables", "95%CI_low", "95%CI_hi"))
> model_std_summary <- summary(model_std)
output_std <- model_std_summary$coefficients |> 
     as.data.frame () |>
     tibble::rownames_to_column("Variables") |>
     left_join (conf_ints, by = "Variables") |> 
     mutate (across(c(2:4, 6:7), .fns = function(x) {format(round(x, 5), nsmall = 5)})) |> 
     relocate (`95%CI_low`, .after = Estimate) |>
     relocate (`95%CI_hi`, .after = `95%CI_low`)
> output_std[ ,7] <- format.pval(output_std[ ,7], eps = .001, digits = 4)
> output_std

           Variables Estimate 95%CI_low 95%CI_hi Std. Error  t value Pr(>|t|)
1        (Intercept)  0.17556  -0.14697  0.49809    0.15728  1.11623  0.27693
2         scale(opi) -0.47667  -0.82894 -0.12440    0.17215 -2.76892  0.01150
3  scale(competence)  0.38072   0.02892  0.73252    0.16909  2.25151  0.03519
4 scale(integration) -0.49318  -0.83997 -0.14639    0.20584 -2.39592  0.02597
5    scale(indegree)  0.26905   0.03395  0.50415    0.15564  1.72862  0.09855
6    scale(voterank) -0.13614  -0.43469  0.16241    0.18372 -0.74103  0.46688


Recall what the intercept does: giving you an estimate for $y$ when all regressors are zero. After scaling, this is now tantamount to asking what happens when all regressors are at their respective mean values. Hence, the intercept now has a very different interpretation, and it is not clear why there should be a clear relationship between its value before and after standardization, and hence nor its significance. As a consequence I also do not think this has anything to do with HC s.e.s.

Thank you, @Christoph-Hanck!

This is unsurprising:

The intercept $p$-value tests whether the outcome differs significantly from $0$ when all explanatory variables equal $0$.
Using scale on both the explanatory variables and the outcome forces the intercept to be zero.

You can demonstrate this with a simulation in R:
require("sfsmisc")
set.seed(1234)
n <- 100
x <- rnorm(n, 2)
y <- 1.5 + 0.5 * x + rnorm(n)

LM  <- lm(y ~ x)
LMs <- lm(scale(y) ~ scale(x))

summary(LM)$coefficients

#              Estimate Std. Error  t value     Pr(>|t|)
# (Intercept) 1.5893240  0.2175899 7.304218 7.493838e-11
# x           0.4739151  0.1037759 4.566715 1.441777e-05

summary(LMs)$coefficients

#                 Estimate Std. Error      t value     Pr(>|t|)
# (Intercept) 1.904569e-17 0.09126601 2.086833e-16 1.000000e+00
# scale(x)    4.188856e-01 0.09172579 4.566715e+00 1.441777e-05

And here is what the scatterplot looks like:


It is surprising that the intercept is not zero. That could be due to the 10 observations with NA values.

Thank you so much, @Frans-Rodenburg!
